# How can I dynamically create an objects of myclass by the code?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="tag1_name" value="tag1"/>
  <add key="tag1_access" value="readWritable"/>
  <add key="tag1_defaultValue" value="0"/>

  <add key="tag2_name" value="tag2"/>
  <add key="tag2_access" value="readable"/>
  <add key="tag2_defaultValue" value="10"/>

  and etc.

</appSettings>
```

And class MyClass.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string tagName;
    public string tagAccess;
    public string tagValue;
}
```

My task is read all the tags from app.config file (it's near 400) and fill it's data to specify properties of object of class. Every class contains these three properties, so I should fill it, and then create a new object of Myclass.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count / 3; i++)
{
    try
    {
        string tag_name = "tag" + i + "_name";
        string tag_access = "tag" + i + "_access";
        string tag_defaultValue = "tag" + i + "_defaultValue";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_name]) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_access]) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_defaultValue]))
        {
            [THERE I SHOULD DYNAMICALLY CREATE OBJECTS OF CLASS]
            ++tag_count;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         logger.ExceptionMessage(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

How can I dynamically create an objects of MyClass by the code when it's needed and then fill their properties of my data from the configuration file?

Comment: I don't think it's the same case. What the OP's looking here is 1. *read* the config file. 2. *create new instance* using `new`. @Ramon, what did you try so far? Show us your code so we can better understand and help

Comment: Sorry for my inaccuracies, i update the question. Can you please to watch it again, please ? I mean, i want dynamically create an objects of MyClass in the for cycle, and then feel it's properties. I just don't know how to create it dynamically, cause it's need specified name for object.

Comment: @Ramon -  just go through provided code to create dynamic properties using ExpandoObject. here one loop can generate 400 properties on one click :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have an constructor in your class and then initialize properties from app.config

```
public MyClass() {
    tagName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_name"].ToString();
    tagAccess = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_access"].ToString();
    tagValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_defaultValue"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But i mean i don't know how to create a lot of objects of `MyClass` in the code. I mean, i know how to create a some objects of class, just use something like `MyClass obj1 = new MyClass()`. But in my code i will have a `for (int i = 1; i <= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count; i++)` construction, and i don't know how many objects i should create. So, is it have some universally solution for it ?

Comment: Try iterating in a loop, and add each instance you create to List<MyClass> - that way you can have as many as you need, but don't need to declare how many you need.

Comment: @OriNachum, thank you! Can you please give me an example, i tried, but nothing works :/

Comment: @Ramon, sure! UmmarAbbas almost did it, but I'd use a simple List<MyClass> instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ExpandoObject` in replacement of `MyClass` in order to create dynamic properties after reading from config file or any other source.

```
var MyClass = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
MyClass.Add("tag1_name", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_name"].ToString());
MyClass.Add("tag1_access", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_access"].ToString());
MyClass.Add("tag1_defaultValue", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_defaultValue"].ToString());
```

This code is same as below and you can use it just like class and it's properties.

```
dynamic MyClass = new ExpandoObject();
MyClass.tag1_name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_name"].ToString());
MyClass.tag1_access = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_access"].ToString());
MyClass.tag1_defaultValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tag1_defaultValue"].ToString());
```

This object can be accessed as following code.

```
object tag1Name = MyClass.tag1_name;
object tag1Access = MyClass.tag1_access;
object tag1DefaultValue = MyClass.tag1_defaultValue;
```

Updated code from Question with dynamics and ExpendoObject:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count / 3; i++)
    {
     try
        {
          string tag_name = "tag" + i + "_name";
          string tag_access = "tag" + i + "_access";
          string tag_defaultValue = "tag" + i + "_defaultValue";
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_name]) &&
              !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_access]) &&
              !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_defaultValue]))
              {

                //THERE DYNAMICALLY CREATED OBJECTS AND PROPERTIES ARE
                var MyClass = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
                MyClass.Add("tag1_name", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_name].ToString());
                MyClass.Add("tag1_access", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_access].ToString());
                MyClass.Add("tag1_defaultValue", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tag_defaultValue].ToString());


                //USING PROPERTIES IN SAMPLE CODE
                object tag1Name = MyClass.tag1_name;
                object tag1Access = MyClass.tag1_access;
                object tag1DefaultValue = MyClass.tag1_defaultValue;

                ++tag_count;
              }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             logger.ExceptionMessage(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Why use `var MyClass = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;` instead of List or Array?

Comment: Because requirement is to load around 400 properties and in case of declaring list of class, user will need to created class with all properties which is too big thing. My code will generate all properties automatically based on loop.

Answer (score 0):

I based this on @OmarAbbas code, but with simpler classes - no need for dynamic, and separated some lines for easier debugging and readability.

```
var myClassList = new List<MyClass>();
for (int i = 1; i <= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count / 3; i++)
    {
     try
        {
          /* Prepare index keys to config */
          string tagNameConfigCode = "tag" + i + "_name";
          string tagAccessConfigCode = "tag" + i + "_access";
          string  tagDefaultValueConfigCode = "tag" + i + "_defaultValue";
          /* If they contain data, we'll create a class from them */
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tagNameConfigCode ]) &&
              !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tagAccessConfigCode ]) &&
              !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tagDefaultValueConfigCode ]))
              {
                  /* Preparing the values - easier to debug and read */
                  var tagNameValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tagNameConfigCode];
                  var tagAccessValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tagAccessConfigCode];
                  var tagDefaultValueValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[tagDefaultValueConfigCode];
                  /* Creating the class for each trio of values */
                  var myClass = new MyClass()
                  {
                       tagName = tagNameValue,
                       tagAccess = tagAccessValue,
                       tagValue = tagDefaultValueValue 
                  };
                  /* Once done, adding to the list - here you'll have all your classes in one place */
                  myClassList.Add(myClass );
              }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             logger.ExceptionMessage(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Ramon wants to get bulk of properties (around 400) that's why I have created expando object where properties can be added dynamically through loop. given code is just an example from Ramon. and creating class and adding hundreds of properties is not feasible solution.

Comment: Actually, 400 properties doesn't sound much for List<MyClass> I've had thousands.
From what I understand, OP wants each set of properties for 1 class, and not 1 class with *all* properties added. Edit: Even if OP does want the second case mentioned, I'd use a dictionary instead.